# Does Sort function not work on List Datatype?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function is supposed to sort the list based on the key value

```
class Solution:
    def frequencySort(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        #print(nums.count(1))
        nums.sort(key=nums.count)
        return nums
```

Nums.count works proper and the key works with sorted() instead. I'm curious to know if I'm missing on something in sort

**Input = [1,1,2,2,2,3]**

**Output = [1,1,2,2,2,3]**

Answer (score 2):

During an in-place sort, the content of the `nums` list is unpredictable.  In my testing it actually appears to be an empty list during the sort, so the count becomes zero.  Below is my test:

```py
def sortkey(x):
    print(id(Input), Input, x, Input.count(x))
    return Input.count(x)

def frequencySort(nums):
    print(id(nums), nums)
    nums.sort(key=sortkey)
    return nums

Input = [1,1,2,2,2,3]
print(frequencySort(Input))
```

Output:

```
2059926758528 [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
2059926758528 [] 1 0
2059926758528 [] 1 0
2059926758528 [] 2 0
2059926758528 [] 2 0
2059926758528 [] 2 0
2059926758528 [] 3 0
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Whereas with `sorted` the object remains unchanged and the count is correct:

```py
def sortkey(x):
    print(id(Input), Input, x, Input.count(x))
    return Input.count(x)

def frequencySort(nums):
    print(id(nums), nums)
    return sorted(nums, key=sortkey)

Input = [1,1,2,2,2,3]
print(frequencySort(Input))
```

Output:

```
3008991075904 [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
3008991075904 [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3] 1 2
3008991075904 [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3] 1 2
3008991075904 [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3] 2 3
3008991075904 [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3] 2 3
3008991075904 [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3] 2 3
3008991075904 [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3] 3 1
[3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

You can use `sort` and gain efficiency if you make a single pass counting all the elements, and use the counts as the key.  `.count()` is making a pass over the list during each key generation of the sort so is very inefficient.

```py
from collections import Counter

def frequencySort(nums):
    counts = Counter(nums)  
    nums.sort(key=lambda n: counts[n])

Input = [1,1,2,2,2,3]
frequencySort(Input)  # in-place
print(Input)
```

Output:

```
[3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: What should I infer from it

Comment: @user18025483 Use `sorted` .  You can't count the items during an in-place sort since it is returning 0 every time due to the original list object appearing as empty during the sort. You'd have to dig into the Python source to learn why.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder what the rationale behind emptying the input is for the in-place sort.